# rvest: handling different number of nested classes

Tags: r, purrr, rvest, tibble

I'm not sure how to describe a problem so I will go directly to the example.
I have a HTML document (`html_doc`) that looks like:

```
<div class="main">
   <h2>A</h2>
   <div class="route">
      X<br />
   </div>
   <div class="route">
      Y<br />
   </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
   <h2>B</h2>
   <div class="route">
      Z<br />
   </div>
</div>
```

Inside each `main`, there's more elements beside `title` and `route` so I'm looking for a scalable solution. Classes in `main` are always the same.
I would like to get a tibble that looks like:

```
id | title | route
1  | A     | X
1  | A     | Y
2  | B     | Z
```

My current try gives me error because there's a different number of rows in `title` and `route`. I also don't know how to index class `main`.

```
tibble(
  title = html_doc %>% html_nodes("h2") %>% html_text(), 
  route = html_doc %>% html_nodes(".route") %>% html_text()
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows a similar strategy as your previous question.  The trick is to loop through each child node creating a seperate data.frame of the title and route and then combining all of individual dataframes into the final result.
This solution does depend on having only 1 title per node.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

page<-read_html('<<div class="main">
   <h2>A</h2>
   <div class="route">
      X<br />
   </div>
   <div class="route">
      Y<br />
   </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
   <h2>B</h2>
   <div class="route">
      Z<br />
   </div>
</div>')

#find all of the parent nodes
mainnodes <- page %>% html_nodes("div.main")

#loop through each parent node and extract the info from the children
dfs<-lapply(1:length(mainnodes), function(id){
  #assume a single title node or same number as routes
  title <- mainnodes[id] %>% html_nodes("h2") %>% html_text() %>% trimws()
  #Count the number of img nodes per parent.
  route <- mainnodes[id] %>% html_nodes("div.route") %>% html_text() %>% trimws()

  tibble(id, title, route)
})

answer<-bind_rows(dfs)
answer

# A tibble: 3 x 3
     id title route
  <int> <chr> <chr>
1     1 A     X    
2     1 A     Y    
3     2 B     Z
```

Comment: Greeeaaat! Can you also include indexing (just in case there are two similar titles)? Each `main` class should have a unique index. Thank you!